# display the options in an autocompletetextfield

Tags: javascript, wicket

Can I display the options in an autocompletetextfield component of wicket  without needing to press the down key?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to solve exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the `Select2` component for Wicket. That is fully customizable.

It is in the wicketstuff project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-select2</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

See here: https://select2.github.io/examples.html